# How to do tuple augmentation

Tags: f#

The following code is from chapter 5 of "F# 4.0 Design Patterns".

```
let a = 1,"car" 
type System.Tuple<'T1,'T2> with 
  member t.AsString() = 
    sprintf "[[%A]:[%A]]" t.Item1 t.Item2 
(a |> box :?> System.Tuple<int,string>).AsString()
```

The desired output is `[[1]:["car"]]`

However, a red squiggly appears under `AsString()`. "The field, constructor or member 'AsString' is not defined. Maybe you want one of the following: ToString"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit odd code sample - I suspect the point that this is making is that F# tuples are actually .NET tuples represented using `System.Tuple` - by showing that an extension to `System.Tuple` can be invoked on ordinary F# tuples.

I suspect the behaviour of F# has changed and it no longer allows this - it may have been that adding extensions was allowed on `System.Tuple`, but not on ordinary F# tuples, but the two have became more unified in the compiler.

However, you can do a very similar thing using the .NET-style extension methods:

```
let a = 1,"car" 

[<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute>]
type TupleExtensions =
  [<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute>]
  static member AsString(t:System.Tuple<'T1,'T2>) = 
    sprintf "[[%A]:[%A]]" t.Item1 t.Item2 

let st = (a |> box :?> System.Tuple<int,string>)
st.AsString()
```

This can actually be also invoked directly on an F# tuple value:

```
("car", 32).AsString()
```